# Reactjs - passing a click event up to parent

Tags: reactjs, events, parent-child

On my child event I have

```
<div className="box" onClick={this.clickBox}></div>
```

On my parent I have the method

```
clickBox() {
  alert('hello');
}
and have bound it with

this.clickBox = this.clickBox.bind(this);
```

This does not work but if I put the method in the child it triggers.

How do I pass the event up to the parent?

Comment: You should pass your method from parent to child.  And access it via props

Comment: You can pass the parent's click even into the child component as a property, then raise this event on click. Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't give you an example.

Comment: Could you post the entire parent, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send `onClick` as a prop to `Child`

```
const Child = ({ onClick }) => <div className="box" onClick={onClick}></div>
```

and then in the parent:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.clickBox = this.clickBox.bind(this)
  }

  clickBox() {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child onClick={this.clickBox}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: that worked a treat,  Is the binding this.clickBox = this.clickBox.bind(this); not required anymore?

Comment: It depends. You can either bind it or make it arrow function like as described [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).